# Populating C++ object fields inside loop is resulting in empty fields

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I'm fairly new to C++ so bear with me.

I will try to explain my problem simply.

I think the code below is simple enough to understand. I have a object DF_XML_Table that has a field 'name'. I am creating instances of the object and assigning values to the name field. It is resulting in empty name fields.

```
vector<DF_XML_Table*> tblVec;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    string tblName = "Name";
    DF_XML_Table xmlTbl;
    xmlTbl.name = tblName;
    tblVec.push_back(&xmlTbl);

}
cout << "tbl[0]->name = " << tblVec[0]->name << endl;
```

Why is this the output?

```
tbl[0]->name =
```

Comment: You `vector` stores pointers, but you `push_back` the address of a variable that will go out of scope each loop (so instead just have `std::vector<DF_XML_Table>` and drop the `&` from the `push_back`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this the output?
>
> ```
> tbl[0]->name =
> ```

---

It's because

> ```
> DF_XML_Table xmlTbl;
> ```

goes out of scope and will be destroyed on each of the loops iterations. You'll have a dangling pointer left, and accessing it later is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

Instead of using raw pointers, you should choose an appropriate [dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) smart pointer to be stored in the `std::vector<>`:

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<DF_XML_Table>> tblVec;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    DF_XML_Table* xmlTbl = ;
    tblVec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<DF_XML_Table>(new DF_XML_Table()));
    tblVec.back()->name = "Name";
}
cout << "tbl[0]->name = " << tblVec[0]->name << endl;
```

The code above will ensure that ownership for the dynamically allocated object is transferred to the containing `vector<std::unique_ptr<DF_XML_Table>>`, and be properly handled to decease their life time no earlier, than `tblVec` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

This is linked to the [lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) of your object.
As you define xmlTbl on the stack, the memory is not allocated on the heap but on the stack, and the pointer to `xmlTbl` (`&xmlTbl`) actually becomes invalid after the `}` brace of the for loop.

What you need to do is allocate these, either by using a `vector<DF_XML_Table>` (instead of `vector<DF_XML_Table*>`), or use `new` to allocate memory (but you will have to call delete on each allocated pointer to avoid leaks.

Comment: This is a simplified version of code. The real code has a vector<DF_Table> where DF_Table is a abstract super class of DF_XML_Table and others. I think I can only have a vector or pointers if the elements are an abstract class? My point is I will have to go with the second option you suggested. It works now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `xmlTbl` object you are creating only exists within the scope of the `for`, once it exits `for` it gets deallocated. Instead:

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<DF_XML_Table>> tblVec;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    string tblName = "Name";
    tblVec.push_back( unique_ptr<DF_XML_Table>( new DF_XML_Table ) );
    tblVec.back()->name = tblName;
}
cout << "tbl[0]->name = " << tblVec[0]->name << endl;
```

Comment: Bad idea. `unique_ptr<DF_XML_Table>` or `shared_ptr<DF_XML_Table>` is a smarter and much safer solution.